# Firebase Google Cloud functions suddenly stop working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm just calling repeatedly (by hand) a simple http function (no database access) deployed on Firebase Functions.

After some calls I start getting to the following error:

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

And the following log:

[image]

What I find really confusing is that no internal exception is thrown and no error information is provided on the log. It doesn't even say 'Function execution started'. I guess I'm exceeding some quota or throttling limit, but there is not a single clue on what is happening.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Contact Firebase support for troubleshooting when you're certain that it's not a coding problem.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: The function just returns a single integer... after like 15 invocations it starts to break.

Comment: Firebase, unless you pay for an upgrade, does have a quota limit, if that helps.

Comment: the same thing happened to me, but no luck.